# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find MSEdge binary error using EdgeDriver and Selenium on Mac through Java

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I have trouble running MS Edge test on MAC using Selenium Remote web driver.

I tried to set System property for edge binary as below:

```
dc = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "/Users/username/Softwares/Work/jars/msedgedriver");
dc.setCapability("edge_binary","/Applications/Microsoft Edge Beta.app");
```

I checked that msedge driver version and version of MS Edge browser that I have installed.
Both are - 80.0.361.48

This is the log on Selenium node:

> 020-02-11 18:06:37.533:INFO:osjshC.ROOT:qtp1800659519-12: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet-59309333: Initialising WebDriverServlet
>   18:06:37.551 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@47c6497e
>   18:06:37.555 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
>   18:06:37.632 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {MicrosoftEdge_binary: /Applications/Microsoft Edg..., browserName: MicrosoftEdge, platform: MAC, version: }
>   18:06:37.633 INFO - Capabilities {MicrosoftEdge_binary: /Applications/Microsoft Edg..., browserName: MicrosoftEdge, platform: MAC, version: } matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriverService)
>   Starting MSEdgeDriver 80.0.361.48 (e1a3ff36578e440880567e6adcbeab38ec2956fa) on port 31883
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Please protect ports used by MSEdgeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

Exception that I get when running code is as

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find MSEdge binary
>   Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
>   System info: host: '****-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14d9:68c6:7d2c:87a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.2', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find MSEdge binary 
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z' 
System info: host: '****-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14d9:68c6:7d2c:87a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.2', java.version: '1.8.0_152' 
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the program was unable to locate MSEdge binary within your system.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though you are using compatable versions of *MS Edge Driver v80.0* and *MS Edge Browser v80.0*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.7.1* of *2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z* which is almost **2.5** years older.
- But your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_152** which is pretty *ancient*.

So there is a clear mismatch between *JDK v8u152* , *Selenium Client v'3.7.1* , *MS Edge Driver v80.0* and the *MS Edge Browser v80.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u241](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.